# Invoking Firebase Function from Firebase hosting code blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I've initialized a templated Firebase project with `functions` & `hosting` features.

I've uncommented the templated HTTP function:

```js
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  res.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

And Also added the following code to the templated `public/index.html` file:

```js
const functions = firebase.functions();
const helloWorld = functions.httpsCallable('helloWorld');
helloWorld().then((res) => { console.log(res); });
```

I've tried making this work with multiple configurations:

1. Firebase emulator for hosting, invoking the deployed Firebase function.
2. Firebase emulator for hosting, invoking the emulated function (Firebase functions emulator).
3. The deployed hosting, invoked the deployed Firebase function.

All configurations yield the following:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I didn't change **anything** in the templated, auto generated Firebase code without the things I stated.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually mixing up [HTTP Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=0) and [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?authuser=0).

Your `helloWorld` Cloud Function code corresponds to an HTTP one but the code in your front-end (i.e. `public/index.html`) calls a Callable one.

You should call the `helloWorld` Cloud Function as a REST API, i.e. with fetch or Axios, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You are mis-matching `onRequest` with `onCall` these are two different methods that are not compatible, resulting in a CORS error because it can't find it.

Change your http type:

- From: `.onRequest((req, res)`
- To: `.onCall((data,context)`

Source: [**onRequest**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) vs [**onCall**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

**General CORS checklist**

- Ensure the function is deployed.
- Ensure the function is the correct Type `onCall` vs `onRequest`.
- Ensure the function name is correct. Typo's and Capitalization matter
- Ensure the function code itself is not throwing an error. Emulator to help debug.
- Ensure your regions match the function with that region, and call it using the region.

Deploying a callable function to a specific region:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.yourFunc = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onCall(async (data, context) =>{
  // ... 
})
```

Calling a function in a specific region from the client:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/functions'
firebase.app().functions('europe-west2').httpsCallable('yourFunc')
Note: firebase.app().function... vs firebase.app.function...
```